# optimizing regex substitution runtime

Tags: regex, perl, optimization

I have some code which does a very large number of regex substitutions. Essentially it boils down to this regex which happens around 50K times on a small example testcase I have:

```
$string=~s/$pattern/$replacement/g ;
```

I am already pre-compiling the pattern via qr// across all patterns (there are around 2.5K patterns in this testcase). I have profiled this with NYTProf, and see that the time used by the subroutines which the regex engine is as follows:

```
# spent  39.7s making 49461026 calls to CORE:regcomp, avg 802ns/call
# spent  7.94s making 49461026 calls to CORE:subst, avg 161ns/call
# spent  6.61s making 49461026 calls to CORE:match, avg 134ns/call
```

However the time taken for this line across the ~50K calls is ~300s according to the profiler. So this essentially means ~53s is used by regex engine, whereas there is a ~250s overhead?? What would this overhead comprise off? I guess the string needs to be dynamically re-allocated in memory after it is modified, but in reality the regex matches only a very few times, so I don't think thats where the overhead is.

Also what else can I do to reduce this runtime? Both pattern and replacement are simple strings which use none of the power of regexes as such (the only real regex character used is word boundary - \b at the beginning and end of $pattern, otherwise just a sequence of fixed word characters)

EDIT:
I actually realized a solution after I asked the question here. Let me clarify how the original code looked like, and then explain the solution if it will help anyone in future.

Simplified original code:

```
foreach my $string (@strings) {
  foreach my $pattern (@patterns) {
    my $replacement = $pattern2replacement{$pattern} ;
    my $compiled_pattern = $pattern2compiled{$pattern} ;
    $string=~s/$compiled_pattern/$replacement/g ;
    # do something with $string
  }
}
```

In the actual code, the inner foreach was in a subroutine with other checks/preprocessing going on before entering the foreach. Also the outer foreach wasn't really a single one but interspersed at many places in code.

Solution:

The key point here is that $string only contained real sub-strings ($pattern) which needed to be replaced with other sub-strings ($replacement). The regex was probably overkill. Though I did have multiple sub-strings which I needed to replace, they were guaranteed to be on a word boundary. Also one thing to note is that a replacement may have itself have a sub-string that is a previous pattern in @patterns. 
eg:

```
 @patterns = ('small', 'blue') ; 
 %pattern2replacement = ( 'small' => 'big and blue', 'blue' => 'black') ;
```

i.e. we expect the string `small pox` to be replaced by `big and black pox`
So the following alternative provides a huge runtime improvement:

```
#Step1: Build complete replacement hash:
my %oneshot_replacement ; 
foreach my $pattern (@patterns) {
  my $replacement = $pattern2replacement{$pattern} ;
  my @splits = split(/\b/, $replacement) ;
  @splits = map {exists $oneshot_replacement{$_} ? $oneshot_replacement{$_} : $_} @splits ;
  $oneshot_replacement{$pattern} = join("", @splits) ; 
}

#Step2: do substitution without regex:
foreach my $string (@strings) {
  my @splits = split(/\b/, $string) ;
  @splits = map {exists $oneshot_replacement{$_} ? $oneshot_replacement{$_} : $_} @splits ;
  $string = join("", @splits) ;
  # do something with $string
}
```

This helped reduce the runtime from ~300s to ~20s.

Comment: Re "*Also what else can I do to reduce this runtime?*", You say you make 50 K calls, but the output shows 50 M calls being made. Each iteration of /g is surely being counted as a separate substitution. Using that definition of substitution, you are doing a substitution every 6 nanoseconds! You really can't go father than. So a faster solution requires a better approach. (Doesn't it always?) Seeing as you provided no information about what you are doing, we can't help you with that.

Comment: "_simple strings which use none of the power of regexes_"  --- but it's done 50,000 times (or is it 50Ms?). That's a big overhead and that's a problem, starting the engine so many times. There may of course be other overheads in code which isn't shown.  So, if you need it faster you need a different approach, as always; as advised already.  If you were to present a specific problem then we could talk more.

Comment: @ikegami - I have added more details along with a solution (which I realized after asking the question).

Comment: Thanks @zdim for your comments. Apologize for not so clear question in 1st place - I have fixed it - yes it was 50M - my bad.

Comment: No problem, thanks for responding.  Didn't get to look carefully, but some immediate observations. (1) The ternary (in the `map`) can be replaced with `$h{$_} // $_` (querying for non-existing key returns `undef` and `//` is defined-or). (2) But then, that `@ary = map { ... } @ary;` copies the whole array.  Why not `exists $h{$_} and $_= $h{$_} } for @splits;`, which should bet faster?  (Or write it as a proper loop, it's only marginally slower that way).  If a hash value can't be  a `0` or `''` (empty string) you can drop `exists`.

Comment: @zdim ```exists $h{$_} and $_= $h{$_} } for @splits``` is probably better, thanks! I don't really understand the implicit $_ variable, will modifying it change the array element in place. If so it behaves more like a reference than a variable?? I wasn't aware of ```//``` operator - thanks for that bit of info.

Comment: @zdim by the way I don't want to use ```//``` since defined $h{$_} would likely lead to autovivification which is a nuisance (yeah I know a perl package exists to do noautovivification, but nonetheless).

Comment: (1) The "topicalizer" in loops (`$v` in `for my $v (...)`) is an alias, indeed. So `$_=2 for @ary;` just made all `@ary` elements into `2` ! (When you don't introduce a loop variable then `$_` is it.)  Try it (2) Good thought for autovivification!  But you're safe here. Again, try: `perl -wE'%h=(a=>1); $h{z} // say "not"; say "ok" if not exists $h{z}'` (one-liner, to run at the command prompt).  So `$h{z}` still doesn't `exists` even after it's been tested by `$h{z}`

Comment: If you are doing millions of calls, you might also want to not have code in a subroutine, but rather think about inlining it. It's ugly, but int his case it will be faster.

Comment: @zdim - thanks for the explanations!!!

Comment: @simbabque errr -- inlining is kind of difficult with this sub called all over the place. Also any future change to this piece of code would be a nightmare. I understand it probably provides runtime benefit, but I will live with the overhead on that front for now.

Comment: #Step2: do substitution without regex:
`foreach (@strings) {
  s{
    \b \w+ \b
  }{ $pattern2replacement{$&} // $& }gex;
  # do something with $string
}`

Comment: @k-mx that's probably a very concise way of expressing it, thanks! But really hard to understand in my opinion. I have used s/$this/$that/g with static replacement strings, but here we are having the global modifier use a different replacement string for each sub-expression and recompute the evaluation of replacement.

Answer (score 1):

About your question where the rest of the 300s is spent the answer will probably be: In the profiler.

Assuming the number of patterns is "relatively low", and that each is a complete word, I would guess that this code is much faster than the substitution without regex:

```
my $or = join("|",@patterns);
$string =~ s/\b($or)\b/$oneshot_replacement{$1}/g;
#print "$string";
```

Anyway in the first code part (#Step1: Build complete replacement hash:)above you have made 2 mistakes:

```
#my @splits = split(/\b/, $pattern) ;
my @splits = split(/\b/, $replacement) ;
```

and if you want to iterate over the array of patterns only ONCE, you have to do this in the correct order (if this is possible at all).

One solution that would work on your example (allowing some kind of expansion) would be

```
#@splits = map {exists $oneshot_replacement{$_} ? $oneshot_replacement{$_} : $_} @splits ;
@splits = map {exists $oneshot_replacement{$_} ? $oneshot_replacement{$_} : exists $pattern2replacement{$_} ? $pattern2replacement{$_} : $_} @splits ;
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the bug in the 1st part! I edited it. Regarding correct order - these patterns are parsed from a file, and its required that the file specifies the patterns in order. Furthermore I don't see how your modification is going to help for a truly unordered case. It still doesnt account for successive need to do replacements (only does one more step).  As regards to overhead spent in profiler - that is hard to digest. If a profiler for runtime is going to report the overhead it causes for profiling the purpose of profiling is pretty much defeated.

Comment: The modification will work with for on one level of substitution - in whatever order the patterns come. To do it correctly, you could add some kind of recursion.